# Non-blocking setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

Is it possible in NodeJS to implement a version of `setTimeout` that wouldn't block the process from exiting once the last line of code has finished?

i.e. the kind of conditional `setTimeout` that would only trigger the callback function provided the process is still running.

**Practical example:**

When implementing a library that initializes itself by setting up some timeouts, you would want that once the app has finished, you don't need to make an explicit call into that library to clear all the timeouts, and let the app shut down regardless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `clearTimeout` if you wanted to maintain references to all your outstanding timers and then clear them as part of your application exit process, but it is much easier in node to use `unref()` [Node doc on `unref`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_unref). The effect is that any `unref`ed timer will not prevent Node from exiting.

For example:

```
var to = setTimeout(myFunction,delay);
to.unref();
```

Works with setInterval as well

```
setInterval(myFunction,delay).unref();
```

Comment: Great answer! And I was being pessimistic if this was possible at all... :) Thank you!!!

Comment: @vitaly-t - You are very welcome. I though it was a very nice convenience when they added it.

Comment: Just so, `clearTimeout ` part shouldn't be in the answer, it is only `unref` that's usable for the kind of example I provided ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t - You could use `clearTimeout` if you wanted to maintain a set of references to active timers, and then have some sort of cleanup function that was called as part of your application exit process. Should have added that in my first sentence in the answer.

Comment: it's just that the point of my question was how to avoid making any explicit calls in the end of the application, and still be able to exit, which is what `unref` does nicely, but `clearTimeout` doesn't help here :)

Comment: @vitaly-t - Got it, understood. The only reason I mentioned it in the first place was to more clearly mark it as the alternative, or really preferred, approach to the first answer provided. I suppose I should have written "while one could use..." as the opening.

Comment: Does this cause any memory leaks? Like, if there's an unref'd timer that never gets cleaned up, does something make sure the timer actually stops along with the process?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs for [setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/docs/v4.2.1/api/timers.html), you will notice that it returns a timeoutObject that can be used to cancel the timeout via `clearTimeout(obj)`.

So what you could do is keep track of all the timeouts you create by storing their id objects. Then you are able end all the timeouts whenever you want.

---

If you simply want to exit the process, ignoring everything else, you can just use `process.exit()` (passing an argument if you want to return a non zero error code).

Comment: I've just added an example to illustrate the point of the question.

Comment: I've extended my answer.

Comment: Thank you, but barry-johnson gave the right answer.